# Remove Safari Navigation Bar on iPhone when body overflow=hidden

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

I'd like to remove the Safari navigation bar when users visit my website from an iPhone.

I've tried
    `window.scrollTo(0, 1)`

and am also using
    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">`
in the header.

The problem is that the body tag of my website is set to overflow=hidden so the scroll command does nothing.

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to work as a preliminary fix in portrait orientation.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; height=416; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```